# Is there a way to make blender using slerp on quaternions?

Tags: add-on, import, quaternion

I'm now working on a blender importer addon.

I have managed to import models and animations extracted from some game into blender successfully. The pose looks perfect most of the time, but at some frame, when rotation is interpolated by blender, the pose suddenly looks very weird.

keyframe and the interpolated result:
[image: keyframe1]
[image: interpolated by blender]

I have tried to solve the problem:

- calculate the the interploated rotation by SLERP
- set and insert it as a new keyframe, then everything looks great

Of course I can calculate every frame by hand, and import all those as keyframes, but that's not what I want to do.

I see that blender python api has a way to do SLERP (mathutils.Quaternion.slerp), so, does blender have some builtin support for slerp ?